# threshold_multiotsu never loads

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

right now i'm trying to use the `skimage.filters.threshold_multiotsu` method to filter n points into k groups. To find the thresholds that split the groups, i'm doing

```
arr=np.asarray([93,86,164,234,310,384,461,538,610,167,245,311,394,470,544,620])
thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(arr,classes=8,nbins=32)
```

This ends up never loading, even after a minute of waiting. Does anybody have some ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `threshold_multiotsu` is written with the ability to specify any number of classes, if you look at the Notes section in the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.threshold_multiotsu), it specifies that the complexity grows exponentially with the number of classes. Here's my timing results for 2, 3, and 4 classes:

```py
In [6]: %timeit threshold_multiotsu(arr, classes=2, nbins=32)
174 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit threshold_multiotsu(arr, classes=3, nbins=32)
5 ms ± 98.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit threshold_multiotsu(arr, classes=4, nbins=32)
873 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It is left as an exercise for the reader to fit an exponential to these three points and figure out the value for `classes=8`, but if we approximate the increase by 100x each time, I get over 1100 days of runtime. (`classes=5` is still running for me.)

In other words, `threshold_multiotsu` is the wrong tool for you if k>4. I might suggest an algorithm such as [kmeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for what you are trying to do!

Comment: Alright, thank you! 1100 days might be to long haha. Kmeans is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Is there a method to predict the number of clusters?

Comment: That's kind of a research question!  But there are some ways to get hints about it. Here's a blog post that shows two useful methods for this: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-determine-the-optimal-k-for-k-means-708505d204eb

Answer (score 1):

On a three-dimensional Array image, the time can be huge to obtain an otsu threshold segmentation using `skimage.filters.threshold_multiotsu` with 7 classes.

A possible solution to drastically reduce the time is to act on the number of bins. By default the algorithm imposes 256 bins (i.e. the default for a grayscale image in general). You can lower to a coarser number (e.g. 128).

For example, I ran the `threshold_multiotsu` with *7 classes* and *128 bins* on a 3D Array image i.e. [MNI152 T1-w template](http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/ServicesAtlases/ICBM152NLin2009)  at 1mm resolution with dimensions 182x182x218 (standard template for Magnetic Resonance Imaging analysis). The elapsed time is about **3 minutes** on my desktop machine.

raw MNI T1-w template

[image: raw MNI T1-w template]

result of 7-calsses segmentation with OTSU method

[image: result of 7-calsses segmentation with OTSU method]